# Transactionable objects in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, transactionscope

*Looking at the code :*

```
class MyClass {  public static int g=1;}

using (TransactionScope tsTransScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //Do stuff here
    MyClass.g=999;
    tsTransScope.Complete();
}
```

- Looking at the "*Do stuff here*" section  : What *type* of objects can I write in there so they can be *Transactionable* ?. I already know that I can write ADO commands and they will be rollback/commited when neccesary. But via `C#` POV : what implementation should a Class has to have in order to be *Transactionable* ( implementing some interface or something ?)
- If it is a `TransactionScope`  as it called , inside a `using` clause (which  is try + finally) , The logic says that if there is a rollback : `MyClass.g` should get BACK its value of 1. however. this is not happening.
  So I guess it is related to the first question. How can I make MyClass *Transactionable* ?

Comment: There are some interfaces to implement to be transactionable, you need to do something when rolling back or comment, do u?

Comment: @MSakherSawan I  _assume_ there is . That's my question actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should implement [`System.Transactions.IEnlistmentNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx) interface, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229975%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229975%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) may help you

For ready-made transactional in-memory storage, there is ([Software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory)), and [STM.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee334183.aspx) it is not a final stuff, but Microsoft is working on it!

A small example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Transactions;

namespace Sakher.Transactions
{
    public class TsansactionalFileWriter
    {
        private FileTransactionEnlistment fileTransactionEnlistment = new FileTransactionEnlistment();
        public TsansactionalFileWriter(string filePath)
        {
            fileTransactionEnlistment.FilePath = filePath;
            Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(fileTransactionEnlistment, EnlistmentOptions.None);
        }

        public void AppendText(string text)
        {
            fileTransactionEnlistment.Content.Append(text);
        }

        public void WriteAllText(string text)
        {
            fileTransactionEnlistment.Content = new StringBuilder(text);
        }
    }

    public class FileTransactionEnlistment : IEnlistmentNotification
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public StringBuilder Content { get; set; }

        public FileTransactionEnlistment()
        {
            Content = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(FilePath, Content.ToString());
        }

        public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
        {

        }

        public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
        {
            //You can create the file here
            preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
        }

        public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
        {
            //Do ssomething when the transaction is rolled-back (You may delete the file if you have created it!)
        }
    }

}
```

Consuming the code:

```
        using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())
        {
            TsansactionalFileWriter writer = new TsansactionalFileWriter("c:\\myFile.txt");
            writer.AppendText("sdfgssdfgsdf");
            tr.Complete();
        }
```

*** EDTI : ADDED G KEEPER FOR ROYI :) ***

```
using System.Transactions;

namespace Sakher.Transactions
{
    public class  Royi_s_gReturnerClass 
    {
        private GReturnerEnlistment fileTransactionEnlistment = new GReturnerEnlistment();
        public Royi_s_gReturnerClass()
        {
            Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(fileTransactionEnlistment, EnlistmentOptions.None);
        }
    }

    public class GReturnerEnlistment : IEnlistmentNotification
    {
        public int GOldValue { get; set; }

        public GReturnerEnlistment()
        {
            GOldValue = MyClass.g;
        }

        public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
        {

        }

        public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
        {

        }

        public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
        {
            preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
        }

        public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
        {
            MyClass.g = GOldValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Your code will be:

```
class MyClass {  public static int g=1;}

using (TransactionScope tsTransScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    Royi_s_gReturnerClass returner = new Royi_s_gReturnerClass();
    //Do stuff here
    MyClass.g=999;
    tsTransScope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: so actually when implementing this interface the value of g will be 1. cool

Comment: You should write the logic of returning the value to its primary value! I am writing a small and good example!

Comment: so writing `throw new Exception()` before `.complete` will actually brings back the value of 1 ( instead of 999) - in my example. right ?

Comment: I will add an example for your g :)

Comment: Added a class to return g to it's value! and added two links.

Comment: I will _ignore_ your last comment. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Deleted it because it is not a stackoverflow issue